# iOS determine how much text fits into a frame

Tags: ios, nsrange

For laying out the text in a view, I would like to know
if it's possible to do the following:

given a string S, frame size and font size => return range (NSRange) of characters
that I can use to substring S, which of course will fit into the frame.

thanks!

Comment: If you are displaying the string in a `UITextView`, you can use the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9283311/77567

Comment: I would like to use CoreText actually since I'm aiming towards an ebook reader.

Comment: Do you want to measure how much text fits in a single line with a fixed width?  Or how much text fits in a given rectangle, with word wrapping?

Comment: The latter, how much text fits in a given rectangle with word wrapping and some font size.