# Count the number of visible character in UILabel while truncated - Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, ellipsis

Is it possible that can count the number of visible characters while truncated?

For example I have a string that has 36 charcters:
`"This is a long looong looong string."`

And it displays on the UILabel like this:
`"This is a long looong..."`

My UILabel has no fixed size, because it can be expanded based on the views above it. If I use `label.text.count`, it returns the whole 36. I want to get only the visible characters (21 or 24 if ellipsis is included on the count).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the number of visible characters by yourself.
Check out these related questions:

[Calculate the range of visible text in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311256/calculate-the-range-of-visible-text-in-uilabel)

[How to get visible text as a string on a textView in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427771/how-to-get-visible-text-as-a-string-on-a-textview-in-ios)